# Can Iterator remove an item not equal to a particular value from the list?

Tags: java, list, iterator

It seems that when I attempt to iterate through a list I cannot remove all items not equal to the one that I wish to keep.

For example, I have the following code:

```
for (Iterator<Alphabet> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Alphabet item = iter.next();
    if (!item.letter().equals("C")) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

I expect that list will be a list of one Alphabet element with the letter "C" but that is not the case.  I actually get an empty list.  How do I change this in order to get my expected result?

Comment: Let's see your `Alphabet` class and how you populate the list.

Comment: Are you sure that "C" is in the list? for debugging try printing out each item and print when you remove an item.

Comment: It's not a real class, I just made that up for an example.  The real purpose is to take a list of company divisions and remove all but the one I'm looking for.

Comment: the item I was looking for wasn't actually in the list.  problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

To answer the question in the title: **yes, an Iterator can remove an item not equal to a particular value**.

The `remove()` operation simply removes the current object.  If the right objects are not being removed, the logic deciding *when* to remove is the problem, not the `Iterator` or its operations.

### Original Answer

If `item.letter()` returns a `Character` type, then `item.letter().equals("C")` will always return false.

If you look at the javadoc for `Character.equals()`, it says:

> The result is true if and only if the argument is not
>   null and is a `Character` object that
>   represents the same `char` value as this object.

So trying to compare it to a `String` (`"C"`) will always fail and remove the object.